# i want to modify Redgate source control Git.xml file to include commit and push

Tags: redgate

Below is an excerpt for the git.xml file in redgates source control

```
<element>
<key type="string">Commit</key>
<value version="1" type="GenericHookCommand">
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\"</CommandLine>
<Verify>exitCode == 0</Verify>
</value>
</element>
```

i wish to modify it to include the push so when you do a commit in management studio it will also the push to git.

i have tried adding another command like

```
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\"</CommandLine>
<commandline>git push</commandline>
```

and also tried

```
 <CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\" && git push</CommandLine>
```

but neither work, any idea on how to get the commit and push working

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the bare ampersands.  Change the line to:

```
<CommandLine>git commit -F "($MessageFile)" -o "($ScriptsFolder)\" &amp;&amp; git push</CommandLine>
```

You may also be able to wrap it in a CDATA, but the above seems to work for me.

Note: If the push or pull requires you to enter a password, then the Red Gate plugin will stall out and force you kill SSMS.  So make sure you can git pull and git push through command line first before updating the XML.

Answer (score 0):

The command file that you get with SQL Source Control was only really designed to sync your local repo, and not to do a push/pull.

I don't think either method you've suggested would work - for the first, I don't think the tool would even know to run the second command, and for the second option I don't believe you can concatenate the commands in that way.

The only suggestion I have (and it's never been tried AFAIK) would be to write your own dos batch file (or powershell if that's your thing) that takes in the same parameters and then runs the two commands you want.

You can then create a new config file for SQL Source Control to execute your batch/powershell instead of git directly.